# After an update, cannot launch any graphical application

Tags: arch-linux, x11, qt, artix-linux

After updating my Artix/Arch Linux distribution with:

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

this is what happens:

- I boot the system.
- I log in with KDE environment.
- All the default graphical applications start correctly after login.
- If I try to launch a console application, from an already open console, it runs successfully.
- I can see the kernel has been updated (5.11.6-zen1-1-zen).
- If I try to launch any graphic application (both from KDE and from the command line), I get this error:

.

```
No protocol specified
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. 
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, 
wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted
```

The problem cannot be fixed reinstalling the application, since this involves every application.

If I login on an LXQt environment, I can launch graphical applications. However I still get warnings (related to Gtk, even for Qt applications like the Kate editor), and the applications do not work properly (e.g. they can be resized but not dragged).

I already tried to rerun `pacman` to see if anything was missing during the update, but from there everything seems to be fine.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days I did another:

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

and the problem is fixed.